# How to display python variable values in VS Code Python Interactive pane markdown cell output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

How can I display the value (as a string) of a python variable in the markdown cell output in the Python Interactive pane of VS Code's MS Python extension?

For a variable `var`, using

```
#%%
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

var = 50 # units

display(Markdown('The value of my variable `var` is: {} units.'.format(str(var)))
```

in a code cell produces the correct output, but I was looking for a more elegant solution that will allow me to insert the value directly into markdown text.

Something similar to the Jupyter notebook extension [Python Markdown](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html).

To show output-number `[10]` with the following is inconsistent, and when it does work only outputs all of the code text as plain text.

```
#%% [markdown]
Out[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many ways in RStudio (like usage backtick `` in Markdown) or assigning parameter with `glue` method or mustaches `{{ var }}` none of them does not work in VSCode for now.  However, you can circumvent this problem by displaying Markdown or HTML within the Python cell. Like below:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame, display, HTML
your_variable = 100
html_skin = f"<h1 style='color:red'>{your_variable }</h1>"
display(HTML(html_skin))
```

What here we did is show `your_variable` within h1 tags and render in the notebook.

It does not answer this problem nevertheless gives the same result.